# React Router 6 using Fragment in Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this code here for a route which works with react router v5

```
<Route
  path="/"
  render={() => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AddPostForm />
      <PostsList />
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
/>
```

How can I refactor it for react router v6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<>
               <AddPostForm />
               <PostsList />
              </>
              }
    />
    </Routes>
```

Comment: Nice it works..

Comment: then marks as correct for future readers